# Can't write to iframe in FF or IE, only Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you run this jsfiddle in CHrome, it will work, but on IE and FF it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/LbFPu/2/

I imagine it has something to do on how each engine writes into the DOM? Is there any way to wait for previous content to be written? Ex:

```
function firstMe(){
    $('body').append('<div id="first"></div>');
    // many other new elements appended
}

function thenMe(){
    $('#first').append('etc');
    // many of the recently appended elements being referenced
}
```

When called in order, I imagine it would work properly in CHrome, but not in IE & FF. Judging by the jsfiddle result.

Anyone ever had to deal with this before?

Comment: On the fiddle, in FF with FireBug, set a breakpoint on the first line of JS and single step and the output will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because you're trying to write to an iframe that's not loaded yet, seems chrome is faster :

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="upload"></iframe>');
var form = $('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image_upload" action="index.php">'
     + '<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple name="img[]" id="image" />'
     + '<br>'
     + '<input type="submit" value="Upload images" class="upload" />'
     + '</form>');

$('#upload').on('load', function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').append(form);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LbFPu/4/)

Comment: Perfect, what is strange is that sometimes it would flicker, I could see the elements inserted for half a second, then the iframe would go blank.

Answer (score -1):

In FF, if you add a `setTimeout()` around the last line of the fiddle it works:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="upload"></iframe>');
var form = $('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image_upload" action="index.php">' + 
    '<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple name="img[]" id="image" />' + '<br>' + 
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload images" class="upload" />' + '</form>');
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#upload').contents().find('body').append(form);
}, 100);
```