# How to create iframe content using javascript in a sandboxed iframe (IE11)?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, sandbox

I am attempting to build a testing page for use in Internet explorer by creating an iframe and dynamically building the iframe contents using javascript or vbscript. I would normally use a data: URI, but IE blocks this.

example.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="javascript:document.write('test')"></iframe>
```

it appears that IE is the only browser that will not allow me to build the iframe contents through a javascript:function() src, even though the allow-scripts sandbox attribute is set. I am not trying to pass any information between the iframe and parent window and do not want to have the allow-same-origin set since it would pretty much defeat the purpose of having a sandboxed iframe.

Are there any other methods to dynamically build the iframe contents other than a javascript or data: URI in the src, or through javascript in the parent window since it will not work with the sandboxed iframe due to same origin restrictions? I also do not want to have to set  the content from an external page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't write to iframe in FF or IE, only Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906859/cant-write-to-iframe-in-ff-or-ie-only-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:` is a kind of weird URI protocol. It works in *some* contexts, like `<a href>`, but not all - for instance, a window's location can not be set to such a URI. (While you can assign a `javascript:` URI to `window.location` as a really roundabout way of running a script, the window's location doesn't stay set to that value.)

To write content into an IFRAME, get a reference to the frame's document and write to it. Doing so will require that you set the `allow-same-origin` sandbox flag.

```
<iframe id="myframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="about:blank"></iframe>

var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var fdoc = frame.contentDocument;

fdoc.write("Hello world"); // or whatever
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wUvrF/1/

Comment: javascript: can be used as a URI in the src attribute of an iFrame in all browsers, so long as the sandbox attribute is not set or is set to allow-scripts in all but IE or allow-same-origin in IE. It appears that this is an issue with same origin as the sandboxed iframe is a unique domain which will keep me from being able to modify it through a script on the parent document. Setting the iFrame to allow-same-origin in the sandbox attribute defeats the purpose of sandboxing the iFrame so it is not a viable option for what I am trying to test.

Comment: You can toggle some option somewhere that will allow you to run javascript URLs from the address bar in Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 defines the "srcdoc" attribute for this purpose

```
<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>Yeah, you can see it <a href=&quot;/gallery?mode=cover&amp;amp;page=1&quot;>in my gallery</a>."></iframe>
```

Comment: The srcdoc attribute is not supported by Internet Explorer, and therefore does not work with what I am trying to do. While it is useful in the other browsers that do support it, I already have ways to dynamically create the iframe source using data or javascript URIs in the src attribute. Unfortunately I need something that works in IE.