# Seamless, Sandboxed srcdoc-iframe in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm currently stuck on a simple task. All i want to do is to create a sandboxed, seamless iframe. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it appears to be empty in IE (11):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin" seamless srcdoc="<p>Yay!</p>"></iframe>
```

I've read, that IE supports the property `security`, but same result.

So, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SoftCreatR/o30mf2cq/

Any idea, how i can make it work in IE10+?

EDIT:

Seems, that i found a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21588091/3334752